# How to Order By season i.e Spring 2020, Fall 2018, Summer 2018 in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Currenly working on a query in WordPress. Semester entries in the DB are stored as strings for example "Spring 2020" "Fall 2018" "Summer 2018" and I need to order them chronologically.

```
$wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s' 
        AND pm.meta_value IS NOT NULL
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'", "semester")
```

Using the default OrderBy in SQL, it sorts them alphanumerically which then outputs something along the lines of

```
Fall 2018
Fall 2019
Spring 2018
Spring 2019
Summer 2018
Summer 2019
```

etc.

Comment: What about winter? `Fall 2018` -> `Winter 2018` -> `Spring 2019`, or `Winter 2019` in the middle there?

Comment: Converting the strings { Fall 2018 Fall 2019 Spring 2018 Spring 2019 Summer 2018 Summer 2019}  into date values and then sort them using the ORDER BY ?

Comment: Can you just add following `order by` clause and let me know, if it works ?


`ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01 ', pm.meta_value), '%d %M %Y') ASC`

Comment: @Tushar, will MySQL parse `01 Spring 2019` as date correctly?

Comment: @markalex  No obviously. As this do not match any of the standard date formats in MySQL

Comment: 1) Split the value into season and year 2) Using a CASE statement, define a numeric column value for each season value to give you the required order 3) sort by the year and this calculated column

Answer (score 3):

Use this order clause:

```sql
order by 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(pm.meta_value, ' ', 2), 
    case SUBSTRING_INDEX(pm.meta_value, ' ', 1) 
        when 'Spring' then 1
        when 'Summer' then 2
        when 'Fall' then 3
        when 'Winter' then 4
    end
```